# Returning two values with arguments in the function

Tags: python, tuples, python-3.4

```
### The formulas for the area and perimeter.
def area(a, b, c):
    # calculate the sides
    s = (a + b + c) / 2
    # calculate the area
    areaValue = (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) ** 0.5
    # returning the output

    # Calculate the perimeter
    perimValue = a + b + c
    # returning the output.

    return areaValue,perimValue

areaV, perimeterV = area(a, b, c)

### The main function for the prompts and output.
def main():
    # The prompts. 
    a = int(input('Enter first side: '))
    b = int(input('Enter second side: '))
    c = int(input('Enter third side: '))

    # The output statements. 
    print ("The area is:", format(areaV(a, b, c),',.1f'),"and the perimeter is:", format(perimeterV(a, b, c), ',.1f'))

### Calling msin
main()
```

I am trying to return the two values from the area function but when I try to do so, I get an error saying the a b and c is not defined when I try to call the function.

Note: My instructor has told us that the area and the perimeter need to be calculated in only 1 function. They can't be separated.

Is there a way I can stop that error from happening?

Comment: You need to put the `areaV, perimeterV = ...` line after the part where you create a, b, and c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put

```
areaV, perimeterV = area(a, b, c)
```

in the main after user input. Because `a,b,c` is defined in the scope of main function

it should be like this:

```
def main():
    # The prompts. 
    a = int(input('Enter first side: '))
    b = int(input('Enter second side: '))
    c = int(input('Enter third side: '))
    areaV, perimeterV = area(a, b, c)
    # The output statements. 
    print ("The area is:", format(areaV,',.1f'),"and the perimeter is:", format(perimeterV, ',.1f'))
```

Comment: Because `areaV` and `perimeterV` are returned values, they can't be called in the formatting as functions of the three side lengths.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Will keep this in mind next time!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `areaV, perimeterV = area(a, b, c)` until you have assigned values to `a, b, c`.